# Issue jquery ResolveClientUrl asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

when i use this in my jquery url it find;

```
 $.ajax({
                                url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/TestJQueryTabStrip.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>',
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ id: itemId })
                            });
```

but when i want to change this to this;

```
 url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/UserControls/Order/OrderProductLicense.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>',
```

it doesnt find. how can i resolve this problem ?

Best Regards

Comment: path problem. is the method in the orderproductlicense.aspx also deleterecord? maybe other parameters?

Comment: is it in orderProductLicense.aspx. but i think url doesnt find.cause same code runing in testjuqery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do like this ..

```
public static class MyUtility
{

 public static string GetAppPath()
    {

        return (System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/") ? string.Empty : System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

    }
}
```

Then refer in jQuery like javascript variable

```
var myOrderUrl=<%= MyUtility.GetAppPath() %>+'/UserControls/Order/OrderProductLicense.aspx/DeleteRecord';

 $.ajax({
          url: myOrderUrl, etc..
```